# Ram and CPU performance in object oriented programming

Tags: performance, oop

I am researching performance principle in object oriented programming.(ex: c#,java) And I read some documents on internet but it didn't illustrative.

I wonder,

- How the impact on performance of using virtual or
  abstract method.
- When using interface or abstract class.
- Performance settings in app.config or web.config in .Net framework.

Can you recommend book, web site, youtube channel, pdf or etc. ?

Thanks in advance. Sorry my language.

Comment: In a properly written compiler, overheads of abstract classes, interfaces and virtual methods are negligible. If they are regular functions, you know at compile-time where they will be. If not, you know where in the vtable you can find a pointer to it so, at most, the overhead is an extra instruction or two - locate the vtable for this object (known at compile time), locate the pointer to the function, call the function. Of far greater impact is the random garbage collection of dynamic variables in "managed code".

Comment: *Can you recommend book, web site, youtube channel, pdf or etc. ?* No, such requests are off-topic here on SO.  This is clearly explained in the help centre.

Comment: It can be an interresting question for your culture but in a pragmatic point of view I think Mike is right. If you want to master your time (for realtime application), you should go for an unmanaged langage (especially without an asynchronous garbage collector). This is where your question take all its meaning. If you don't need realtime I wouldn't recommend to privilege these kind of optimizations over a strong OOP architecture.